# File Upload dialog is not picked by selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, firebug, inspector

[image]

I am trying to write a selenium based test in python.
Here, I am trying to select a file for the first text box(`PGP Private Key`)

Please note - 
1. The text box(`PGP Private Key`) is read only(I cannot enter any text by keyboard)
2. `self.driver.send_keys(file)` is not working.

As I mentioned in note, since `send_keys()` not working, I am trying to get the handle of 'File Upload' dialog.
But `self.driver.window_handles`returns only one handle. That is of main window.

How to upload the file? Any one of these 2 solutions(send_key or window handle) is fine.

Please note, I am using firefox 28 and selenium 2.41.0

Comment: Can you provide `HTML` code for `PGP Private Key` input field?

Comment: There are two lines for that -

`<input id="PGPPrivateKey" class="col-lg-2 ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" type="text" readonly="" required="" ng-model="privateKey"></input>
<input id="selectKeys" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" type="file" name="pgpPrivateKeyFileData" ng-model="pgpKeyFile"></input>`

Comment: You should handle not `<input type="text">` element, but `<input type="file">` instead

Comment: Note that Firefox 28 is very outdated. You should update to the current version 49.0.1. How far is your question related to Firebug?

Answer (score 0):

In common case this code should work:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='selectKeys']").send_keys(path_to_file)
```

Comment: Unfortunately did not work. I got ElementNotVisibleException.

Comment: Do you make a click on `Select Private Key` button before executing my string ?

Comment: No. I am not doing that. Should I?

Comment: No. I just guess what could make input field be not visible

Comment: Another guess... can you try this line before sending path to file: `driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("selectKeys").style.visibility="visible";')`. same result?

Comment: Tried it. no luck :-(